# possible to set up kubernetes monitoring in a different namespace

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possoble to have an ELK stack setup, in a "monitoring" namespace in kubernetes, that has read permission accross all the other namespaces so that i can still monitor all the pods.

Im just wondering if that would just make it a little easier to manage?, especially when it comes to accessing other namespaces, where we have resrtictions.

I know prometheous allows this, but has anyone tried with a ELK stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can be done. Following is the step by step guide to setup EFK stack on kubernetes in logging namespace.

> https://blog.ptrk.io/how-to-deploy-an-efk-stack-to-kubernetes/[enter link description here](https://blog.ptrk.io/how-to-deploy-an-efk-stack-to-kubernetes/)

I am sure we can do the same for log-stash also.